# Enter one thing but save the other

Tags: entities

I try to construct a field and I wonder how should I implement this process via Field API:

1. User enter some data to the field. Let's say, the data entered is a node title.
2. User hits the "Save" button, but what is actually saved in the database is the node ID of the node whose title has been entered by the user.

Something like this happens with the Entity Reference module: I enter the title of the entity (as I 'm getting assistance through autocomplete), but the module saves `target_id`, not the title I have actually entered.

How can I gain such behavior?

Comment: You means title not saved in databae?

Comment: Yes, drupal should search for the node that have the same title and save its nid (target_id). Node's title shouldn't be saved.

Comment: This is strange, drupal work by nid, if you be in edit page of node,any change updated the node ,not add another node

Comment: Mm. I don't know how to paraphrase it. Consider this example: in the widget user selects his location by typeing coordinates but what is saved in database is the name of the city. Or this one: User enters the integer but drupal wants to save it's "word representation": entered 2 is saved as "two", entered 3 is saved as "three". All this stuff requires some process function and the question is basically if Drupal can save not entered data but the processed data that possibly hav different data type.(i.e. "int" is saved as "string")

Comment: @DimsG, ok, I understand what is your problem, this is not issue and its big feature(realated to database engineering conception and realationship conceptition ). What do you intend?

Comment: @DimsG, what do you intend, where you want use this data ,in views, please get me more details form better solution for you

Comment: Sorry, hadn't any access to internet. Well, my client wants to have a field that is actually a container of two default fields: an (1) entity reference and a (2) text field.  These two fields should be in one logic group since they refer to one object -- entity reference refers to the "related book" and text field contains the information about on what pages the current node( a real article in that related book). As I don't know any method to use existing module "Entity Referrence", I have to implement my "restricted" version of it. So I have to implement an autocomplete feature

Comment: where editor enters node's ("related book") title but what is actualy saved is "target_id". It's done in Entity Reference but I don't know how. Inspecting the code hadn't help since I'm not quite familiar with Field API. Thank you

Comment: another question is where you use this nodes in views? I have a plan if you think I understand you means correctly tell me suggest my code to you. by default entity ref field saved nid of refrenced  node, but If we can save refrenced field title in another field in submit .

Comment: In current situation this information (to be specific, related book info, i.e. reference itself and bibliographical data) should be visualized only once, so I think that I'll do it without Views, just having written the module with Field Search Query or Database API. Not good idea, I agree, but if I write my own module, adding a Views compatibility will be really hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a module for example module name is rose. In that module implement  hook_node_validate

```
function rose_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
       //Check to see if this is the node form data you want to change
    if ($form['#form_id'] == 'contentType_node_form') {
        //based on the value provided in 
        $form_state['input']['field_name']['und'][0]['value'];
        $new_info_data = 'some logic'; //get the data you would like to save .
        variable_set('new_info', $new_info_data); //Save the data in a variable.
    }
}
```

Then implement a hook_node_presave. As per our example

```
function rose_node_presave($node) {
    //check if the node type is the one you want to change the value
    if ($node->type == 'content_type') {
        $new_info = variable_get('new_info'); //get the value which was set in validation variable_set()
        $node->field_name['und'][0]['value'] = $new_info;
    }
}
```

I have implemented this on Drupal 7. A user enters instagram user name and I get the instagram id from instagram api and save it. Let me know if more explanation is required.

In this implementation users enters only address I get the Lat and Lng based on the address provided and save it in the database.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant. However it seems to be really strange. Please tell me, if I got it right: Drupal requires for field-edit-form (widget) to have one input for one column (in db)? I.e. there is no Drupal way to form the data structire I want it to be? Because your solution is a kind a crutch to fix Drupal's inability.

Comment: By the way, how to implement it in the opposite direction, i.e. in your example, when user tries to edit the node he sees instagram name, not the id (i.e. to "process id back" to username)

Comment: In my case to solve "opposite direction" problem I used username filed  data to get the user id and populated it in another filed and saved both.

Comment: I also used a similar approach where a user enters an address in some fields, based on info in these fields I send a request to google's map api and get the lat and lng for that address and save it in additional fields database.

Comment: @dkiscool,your answer maybe worked but it is irregular.

Comment: @zhilevan I would love to get detail on some alternative way to accomplish similar task.

Answer (score 1):

ok.let's suppose your entity ref field name is `field_entity_ref`
you should to create anther field (text) field , name it `field_book_title`
in you custom module `hook_form_alter`

```
  function custommodule_form_alter($form, &$form_state,$form_id) {
     if ($form_id == 'yourcontetntpe_form_node') {
        $form['#submit'][] ='mycustom_function';
        // we must hide shadow field in view 
        // first check #access=false if not work comment it and use hide
         $form['field_book_title']['#access'] = false;
        // or you can hide it
        // hide($form['field_book_title']);
       }
   }
```

and in `mycustom_function` function  get nid of refrenced node , load node and save it's title in `field_book_title`.

```
function mycustom_function(form,&$form_state) {
  $node = node_load($form_state['values']['field_entity_ref']['und'][0]['target_id']);
  $form_state['values']['field_book_title']['und'][0]['value'] = $node->title; 
 }
```

And finally in view of node (in your tpl or in views) use `field_book_title` instead of `field_entity_ref`

I hope this be useful for you.